# (a) Find a recurrence relation for the number of ternary strings of length $n$ that do not contain two consecutive 0s or two consecutive 1s.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I tried this in a way like 
my assumption is that $${T_n}$$ be a string with no consecutive zeros and one's,and now calculating for starting bits in the sequence is as follows

01=$$T_{n-2}$$

02=$$T_{n-2}$$

2=$$T_{n-1}$$

so I got the answer as $${T_n}=2*T_{n-2}+T_{n-2}$$

But the given answer is $${T_n}=2*T_{n-1}+T_{n-2}$$.

Comment: You posted [the same question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3576085/find-a-recurrence-relation-for-the-number-of-ternary-strings-of-length-n-that-do) under a different name a minute ago, and deleted it when people pointed out that what you wrote was unreadable.  Why not try to improve your question instead?

Comment: I have no idea what $01=T_{n-2}$ means.  Is $T_n$ a string?  Is $T_n$ a number?

Comment: The usual way to solve problems like this is to divide the good strings into categories.  Let $A_n$ be the number of good strings of length $n$ that end in $0$.  $B_n$ same ending in $1$, $C_n$ the same ending in $2$.  Easy to get recursions for each of those, then sum them up.

Comment: @lulu here 01 means string first two digits of 01 and remaining are any digits without consecutive 0's or 1's.

Comment: Please edit your post to explain what your notation means, it is still very unclear.  Start by defining $T_n$ properly.  If, as I suspect, it is a number then it makes no clear sense to say that it equals a ternary string.

Comment: To solve the problem, follow my hint (with $A_n,B_n,C_n$).  I think you'll find that quite straight forward.

Comment: Try to follow my hint.  It only takes a couple of lines.  Alternatively, the posted solution from @MatthewDaly is fine. Same idea as in my hint with the helpful observation that $A_n=B_n$ by symmetry.

Comment: @lulu I am not getting the solution of Matthew ,I had edited my post can you please explain in the way i had taken.

Comment: As I have said, I do not understand your approach.  Please take some time to follow either my hint or the posted solution.  To follow my hint, start by showing $A_n=B_{n-1}+C_{n-1}$ with similar recursions for $B_n,C_n$.

Answer (score 2):

There might be easier ways to think about it (combinatorics is like that), but here is my idea.

Let's think about the $T_n$ sequences of length $n$.  Clearly, $T_{n-1}$ of them end in 2.  Of the rest, because of the $0-1$ symmetry in the problem, half of them end in $0$ and half in $1$, which is $\frac12(T_n-T_{n-1})$.

So how many sequences of length $n+1$ will there be?  Of the sequences that end in $2$, there are three allowable ways to add a trit to the end.  (A trit is a ternary digit.)  Of the sequences that end in $0$ or $1$, there are two allowable trits that can continue the sequence since you cannot repeat that last trit.  Therefore,

$$T_{n+1}=3T_{n-1}+2\left(\frac12(T_n-T_{n-1})\right)=3T_{n-1}+T_n-T_{n-1}=T_n+2T_{n-1}$$